# Documenting re-exported functions in an R package

Tags: r, namespaces, documentation

I'm in the process of splitting one of my R packages into two, since it incorporates two logically distinct sets of functionality, one of which is more general than the other. However, since the original package is reasonably popular, and is depended upon by at least one other package, I don't want to break compatibility.

R's namespace system provides a way to handle this, by importing the functions now in the split-off package (which is [`RNifti`](https://github.com/jonclayden/RNifti)), and then re-exporting them from the downstream package (which is [`RNiftyReg`](https://github.com/jonclayden/RNiftyReg)). That way, third-party users and packages can load just `RNiftyReg`, and still see functions that now actually belong in `RNifti`. Moreover, the documentation for these functions still works, since the `RNifti` namespace is loaded along with `RNiftyReg`.

However, `R CMD check` complains, because the re-exported functions are not documented in `RNiftyReg`.

So my question is: **what is the best practice in this scenario?**

I seem to have three options, none of which appeal very much.

- Break existing code by requiring the new package, `RNifti`, to be loaded alongside `RNiftyReg` for all the previously-available functions to be available. Clearly that's undesirable.
- Duplicate all the documentation for these functions in the downstream package, `RNiftyReg`. That should keep everyone happy but is messy to maintain, and can easily get out of sync if the packages are not always updated together.
- Provide a single catch-all documentation page for all of these functions in `RNiftyReg`, pointing to the full documentation in `RNifti`. But that still needs to be kept in sync with respect to function arguments, and it requires users to use the ungainly `?RNifti::somefun` syntax to see the "real" documentation.

Is there a way around this, or it simply unwise to re-export code like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From some further poking around, it looks like `\docType{import}`, added in R version 3.1.1, is the best available mechanism for handling this scenario (as noted in [this `roxygen2` issue](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/408)). This seems to effectively behave like my third option above, but it has the advantage of not documenting the function arguments explicitly, so they don't have to be kept in sync.

It seems that `roxygen2` syntax like

```
#' @export
RNifti::xform
```

generates the right form of .Rd file, and satisfies `R CMD check`. I wasn't using this particular syntax before, which is why the issue remained outstanding.

I've confirmed that this works with an unmodified third-party package, so it looks like the best bet.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't aware of the docType import.

Comment: It looks like you now need to also include `#' @importFrom <package> <function>` to get `roxygen` to document it correctly. See e.g. https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/R/reexport-tibble.r

Answer (score 2):

I would not import all these functions only to export them again. For these kind of things, the most logic thing to do seems to make the package RNiftyReg dependent on the package RNifti.

So you add to the Depends field in the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Depends:
    RNifti
```

To be 100% sure that you use the correct functions from RNiftyReg, you can call them using the `::` operator in your code, eg:

```
RNifti::aNiceFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

You can add RNifti to the Depends field and still import the package through the NAMESPACE file. This is necessary if you want to keep the functions of `RNifti` available for packages that only import the namespace of `RNiftyReg`.

In that case you do NOT mention it in the Imports: field of the DESCRIPTION file. As the manual says, a package should be mentioned only in one of both. And as you want the namespace of RNifti to be attached, you have to mention it in the Depends field.

So this is actually your 1st option, but done in such a way that the user hardly notices this happens. `library('RNiftyReg')` will now automatically attach RNifti as well.

Comment: Yes, this is a perfectly sensible solution. I guess I've been gradually conditioned to use `Imports` over `Depends`, so now I tend to forget the latter still exists... :)

Comment: If it were just one or two functions, I would make the documentation page for the function in `RNiftyReg` be as minimal as possible with several express statements to see `\code{\link[RNifti]{fn_name}}`.  But if you're truly dependent on `RNifti` for `RNiftyReg` to function, then Joris Meys has given sage advice.

Comment: Actually, this isn't a full solution, because while it works for user sessions where `library(RNiftyReg)` is called, it doesn't work for third-party packages that only import `RNiftyReg`. Running `R CMD check` on one such package still reports "missing or unexported objects".

Comment: @JonClayden Did you try it? If RNifti is added in the Depends field, R CMD check will attach that one before running the checks afaik. Furthermore, using the full `RNifti::myfun()` notation will make sure all functions are found. Such behaviour can only happen imho if you rely on functions not exported by RNifti in the 3rd package, but that's a design no-no if you ask me. You can import RNifti in the RNiftyReg namespace as explained above. No need to export the RNifti functions as long as you have RNifti under Depends.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. The third package imports `RNiftyReg`, so it loads its namespace **but does not attach the package**. Since `RNiftyReg` is not attached, neither is `RNifti`, and hence the functions in `RNifti` are not available. The third package would have to depend on `RNiftyReg` and/or import `RNifti` to make this work, and I don't want to impose that requirement on third parties

Comment: @JonClayden I see your point, that's right (but a design flaw imho). Then you can still import RNifti in the namespace of RNiftyReg, but keep RNifti in the Depends field as I explained before. When the namespace of RNiftyReg is imported in a third package, the one of RNifti is imported with it and everything should work as before.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, you can get a list of re-exported functions using:

```r
exported <- getNamespaceExports("package")
all_ls <- ls(envir = asNamespace("package"))
exported[!exported %in% all_ls]
```

So, for `dplyr` for example:

```r
exported <- getNamespaceExports("dplyr")
all_ls <- ls(envir = asNamespace("dplyr"))
# let's sort them too
exported[!exported %in% all_ls]
#>  [1] ".data"         "%>%"           "add_row"       "all_of"        "any_of"       
#>  [6] "as_data_frame" "as_label"      "as_tibble"     "contains"      "data_frame"   
#> [11] "data_frame_"   "ends_with"     "enexpr"        "enexprs"       "enquo"        
#> [16] "enquos"        "ensym"         "ensyms"        "everything"    "expr"         
#> [21] "frame_data"    "glimpse"       "intersect"     "last_col"      "lst"          
#> [26] "lst_"          "matches"       "num_range"     "one_of"        "quo"          
#> [31] "quo_name"      "quos"          "setdiff"       "setequal"      "starts_with"  
#> [36] "sym"           "syms"          "tbl_sum"       "tibble"        "tribble"      
#> [41] "type_sum"      "union"
```